# Javascript and .NET circular dependency

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

A .NET application I've been working on is hanging on a certain function call, and I think it is because there are a certain 4 function creating circular dependency. I've included an outline of the functions and other functions that they call:

**Javascript**

```
// Fires on user scroll event
function ScrollHandler() {
    //...
    // Calls the following C# function when a user scrolls
    window.external.UserScroll();
}

// Called by C# function UpLoadJson()
function drawTimeline(JsonData) { 
    //...
}
```

**C#**

```
// Called by Javascript function ScrollHandler()
void UserScroll()
{
    //...
    UpLoadJson();
}

void UpLoadJson()
{
    //...
    browser.Document.InvokeScript("drawTimeline", new String[] {data});
}
```

Using "`->`" to denote a function call, what I think is happening is:

`ScrollHandler(/*JS*/) -> UserScroll(/*C#*/) -> UpLoadJson(/*C#*/) -> drawTimeline(/*JS*/)`

But the Javascript can't run `drawTimeline()` because it is waiting for `ScrollHandler()` to return first; this can't return until `drawTimeline()` is called though.

Is this possibly why my application hangs on this function call? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried turning off the scroll handler before UploadJson, then turning it back on?  Starting off like, $(window).unbind('scroll'); ...

Comment: So unbind the `ScrollHandler()` function from within itself before calling `UserScroll()`, and then re-binding after the call? I don't see how that would fix the dependency if the function still has to return before anything else can happen.

Comment: From what I'm reading on other questions, it looks like Ajax will solve it.